# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"13306"'

Tags: python, python-3.x, redes, networking, port

Estoy tratando de probar si tengo el script de actualización ETL correcto en una base de datos MySQL.

He configurado las variables de entorno :

```
set HOZANA_DATA_DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
set HOZANA_DATA_DB_PORT="13306"
...
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el script me sale el error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>py -m etl.task.crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.py", line 2, in <module>
    from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\mysql\connect.py", line 7, in <module>
    db_port = int(os.environ['HOZANA_DATA_DB_PORT'])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"13306"'
```

No entiendo, ¿no es un entero?

Comment: eso es un string un entero no seria `set HOZANA_DATA_DB_PORT=13306` sin comillas??

Comment: quítale las comillas :/

Comment: En Linux la conversión a entero funciona sin importar como hayas escrito el `set`: con o sin comillas, comillas dobles o simples. Da igual, la representación interna `os.environ`  es siempre la misma: una cadena de digitos sin nada añadido.